# Another PHP Insert Bug

Tags: php, mysql

This is the second time today debugging, that the mysql_query INSERT statement has given me major problems.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
$type = $_GET['type'];    
$title = $_GET['title'];
$activitytype = $_GET['activitytype'];
$desc = $_GET['desc'];
$thedate = $_GET['deadline'];
$amtppl = $_GET['amtpeople'];
```

So, all the variables are correct (as echoed by my own console), so it's purely based on mysql INSERT statement again.

```
  mysql_query(" INSERT INTO activity 
(`username`, `title`, `details`, `datetime`, `people`, `activitytype`)
  VALUES ('$username', '$title', '$desc', '$thedate', '$amtppl', '$activitytype')");
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with it here? The properties are all correct (Closely proof read each and every one).

Using mysql_error();
I get an error called:

> Duplicate entry '0' for key 1

Thanks a ton, Chris.

Comment: Is there a warning or an error? Also, careful about SQL injection on your GET data.

Comment: can you print out the mysql_error()? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what the "major problems" are?

Comment: The major problem is that it does not insert into the database. No error.

Comment: Have you connected to the server *and* selected a database?

Comment: Obviously, all other inserts in the file work except for this one.

Comment: @CCates In that case, I find it very hard to believe there aren't any errors reported

Comment: make sure you call mysql_error before doing any other sql work.

Comment: No errors reported on output. Soooo why is it not being inserted into my database?

Comment: I get worried when I see PHP code not using [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. I hope you are sanitizing your variables in code that hasn't been pasted here. If not, please consider re-writing the code to use PDO Prepared Statements rather than trying to sanitize your variables.

Comment: Have you printed out the result of mysql_error() RIGHT after doing the query?

Comment: Would the space before INSERT break it? Or would the mysql server handle that fine?

Comment: Thanks, I got the error now: Duplicate entry '0' for key 1 That is what mysql_error() outputted... Lolwut?

Comment: @CCates: Do you have a `PRIMARY` or otherwise `UNIQUE` key in `activity` that's not also `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: I have an id that is unique. I just realized that I didn't put auto_increment. Wow, I kind of wish that it would tell me these sort of things. Really should check EVERY single thing before I post a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you don't have `auto increment` on your `primary key`. Please make it `auto increment`

Other wise for unique index you should get last insert id or max id of that column and assign last insert id +1 form unique key column i.e make it unique.

Comment: That's not going to change anything, double-quoted strings are interpolated in PHP. (Also, maybe check your typing before you post your answer.)

Comment: As I said before, I proof read very closely each value. I have inputted the correct property values.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this before your code

```
 $_GET = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET)
```